# Passing managedobject from uitableview to textfield to edit in core data model

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a viewcontroller that has a uitableview being populated by my core data model. I am trying to set this up so I can tap on an item in the uitableview, have that item pass to a uitextfield on a second viewcontroller, where it can be edited and then saved back to my core data model.

**prepare for segue**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditItemSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        Item *item = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [segue.destinationViewController setItemname:[item valueForKey:@"itemname"]];
    }
}
```

**error**

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EditItem setItemname:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Im pretty sure the error indicates that i am trying to perform an action on an object that isnt allowed.

Some help . push in the right direction would be appreciated.

**edititem.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface EditItem : ViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *editItemField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *toDoItemName;

@end
```

**edititem.m**

```
#import "EditItem.h"

@interface EditItem ()

@end

@implementation EditItem

@synthesize editItemField;
@synthesize toDoItemName;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    editItemField.text = toDoItemName;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

**edit**

This is what I tried in my viewWillLoad

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [editItemField setText:toDoItemName];
}
```

Comment: Your error tells that EditItem hasn't any implementation for method setItemname. Can we see EditItem.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setItemname:` when you should be calling `setToDoItemName:`.

Comment: Oh wow.  I cant believe I missed that.  Is my edititem implementation correct? now when i tap on an item, it doesnt populate the uitextfield

Comment: You may need to have that code run in `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad`.